# Google Maps Marker Icon got blur in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps-markers, blur

I'm using Xamarin.Android. My app is using custom icon for Google Marker. I created an png image size 72x72 pixels. I used this code:

```
MarkerOptions myMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions ()
                .SetPosition (latLng)
                .SetTitle (Resources.GetText (Resource.String.here_you_are))
                .Draggable (true);

            myMarkerOptions.SetIcon (BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource (Resource.Drawable.marker_my_location));
```

It displayed correctly in Google Maps but unfortunately, my png marker looked quite blur. I don't know why

So what is the cause to this problem and which is the best size for marker to display perfectly in Google Maps?

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: what is your icon size.

Comment: @Destro it's 72x72 pixels as I mentioned in post

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you will need to have various sized icons in order to support different screens.  Each should go in the relevant subfolder under the drawables folder.

The icon sizes for the various screen resolutions should use the following multipliers:

```
LDPI should be x 0.75.
MDPI should be x 1.
TVDPI should be x 1.33.
HDPI should be x 1.5.
XHDPI should be x 2.
XXHDPI should be x 3.
XXXHDPI should be x 4.
```

Comment: thank for your answer. I knew this and I tried to produced these icon sizes and put them to appropriate Drawable folder but it always choose a smallest. Looks very small. Actually, i want to display a bigger one. So that is why i created 72x72.

Comment: when I put that image in the xhdpi folder the image was nice but it was very small so it must have been scaling the image up which would then make sense with the resolutio

Comment: I updated my answer to show what multiplier you should use instead.

Comment: So this also means that this marker size should be meet 512x512 to have a great looking

Comment: For which screen?  The highest resolution you will need is XXXHDPI, which is 72 * 4 = 288 x 288 (but you can probably live with 256 x 256).

Comment: I tried 256x256 i did not remember exactly but it looks good but very small :( i will try again. I would treat 72x72 is size for mdpi